# Error when importing "date-fns" into a Svelte Module

Tags: npm, svelte, rollup, svelte-3, date-fns

I get the following error when trying to build my Svelte app:

```
[!] Error: 'default' is not exported by node_modules\date-fns\esm\index.js, imported by src\components\Month.svelte
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#error-name-is-not-exported-by-module
src\components\Month.svelte (2:11)
1: <script>
2:     import dateFns from 'date-fns';
```

I ran `npm install date-fns` first, so the package exists within my project. I'm using the default rollup config that is created by using the degit template.

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that `date-fns` doesn't feature a default export, as stated by the error message.
Try importing the methods you need by name, for example:

```js
import { format, compareAsc } from 'date-fns'

format(new Date(2014, 1, 11), 'MM/dd/yyyy')
//=> '02/11/2014'

const dates = [
  new Date(1995, 6, 2),
  new Date(1987, 1, 11),
  new Date(1989, 6, 10),
]
dates.sort(compareAsc)
//=> [
//   Wed Feb 11 1987 00:00:00,
//   Mon Jul 10 1989 00:00:00,
//   Sun Jul 02 1995 00:00:00
// ]
```

You might also have to import specific submodules and/or locales depending on your specific requirements. The [date-fns documentation](https://date-fns.org/v2.19.0/docs/Getting-Started) is quite thorough, you should find all the answers you need there.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, that makes sense. If you don't mind, could you please explain why importing the methods individually gets around this problem?

Comment: In this particular case, the author of the package has chosen to export named methods only. Some other packages might *only* offer a default export and *no* named exports, and many will offer both a default *and* named exports. It's strictly a matter of what the author of how a given package chooses to structure their code and how they want to expose their package's methods. You can usually tell how to import any package into your code by taking a quick look at its documentation.